# Error When Doing User Authentication With YII - Property "User.title" is not defined

Tags: php, authentication, yii

I am trying to do database login for a YII app, and I am getting this error. Here is my code:

```
<?php

/**
 * UserIdentity represents the data needed to identity a user.
 * It contains the authentication method that checks if the provided
 * data can identity the user.
 */
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
    /**
     * Authenticates a user.
     * The example implementation makes sure if the username and password
     * are both 'demo'.
     * In practical applications, this should be changed to authenticate
     * against some persistent user identity storage (e.g. database).
     * @return boolean whether authentication succeeds.
     */
    private $_id;
    public function authenticate()
    {
        // $users=array(
        //  // username => password
        //  'username'=>'password',
        // );
        // if(!isset($users[$this->username]))
        //  $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
        // elseif($users[$this->username]!==$this->password)
        //  $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        // else
        //  $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
        // return !$this->errorCode;

        $record=User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));
        print_r($record); 
        echo ($this->password); 
        echo ($record->password); 
         if($record===null)
             $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
         else if($record->password!==$this->password)
             $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
         else
         {
             $this->_id=$record->id;
             $this->setState('title', $record->title);
             $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
         }
         return !$this->errorCode;

    }

    public function getId()
    {
         return $this->_id;
    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

[image]

As a note, I have tried to remove the `$this->setState('title', $record->title);` code, but that just caused another error. I have looked at the values of the `User`, and there is no title, I thought that might be what is causing the error, but like I said, when I remove the call, I get another error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in
>   /home/fredgran/public_html/yii/framework/web/auth/CWebUser.php on line
>   229

Comment: If the User model doesn't have a title attribute, then setting $record->title will always send an error.  As far as the other error (relating to getId), it would be helpful to see the code that calls the getId() method.

Comment: @ews2001 that method is in the code. `public function getId()
    {
         return $this->_id;
    }`

Comment: I see the function, but where are you **calling** getId()?  The error above mentions calling getId() on a non-object, so I'm wondering where getId is being used? Maybe in your UserController?

Comment: Put a `die();` after `print_r($record->attributes);` and let us know what the result is.

Answer (score 0):

remove `print_r($record); 
        echo ($this->password); 
        echo ($record->password);`

and  change line 44 to

```
if(isset($record->title))
      $this->setState('title', $record->title);
```

error "Call to a member function getId() on a non-object" is because calling Yii::app()->user->id;

Please copy your User model if the above fix is not working

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple. This part of the code causes it.

```
 else
 {
     $this->_id=$record->id;
     $this->setState('title', $record->title);
     $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
 }
```

Make sure you have a column called "title" in your user table or whatever the table that your user model refers to.

With this line,

```
$this->setState('title', $record->title);
```

you are trying to create a session variable called "title" and assign user record's title column value.

This is a example of how to set a session and retrieve it in yii.

```
Yii::app()->user->setState('username', $record->username); // define
Yii::app()->user->username // retrieve, can be access anywhere in the system
```

Read here for more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#setState-detail

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Observe the `stack trace` in errors (Attached sceen-shot)

> CActiveRecord->__get("title")

The meaning of this error is "You are accessing the the property which is not defined in the Model". ie, your `User` table does not have the column `title`.

Please print and check the `$record` object. Also check Typo error to track the error.

Answer (score -1):

You are not defining `title` attribute in your database. But, if you want to make a login task, just try this:

```
else
     {
         $this->_id=$record->id;
         //$this->setState('title', $record->title);
         $this->username = $record->username; //try this code
         $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
     }
```

CMIIW

Answer (score -1):

There is no "title" field in database for user table ... you are trying to use that as $record->title so you are getting this error.